# Почему for считает,сколько раз я вводил символы

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
int sum = 0;

// Разрешаем пользователю ввести до 10 чисел
for (int count=0; count < 10; ++count)
{
    std::cout << "Enter a number to add, or 0 to exit: ";
    int val;
    std::cin >> val;

    // Выходим из цикла, если пользователь введет 0
    if (val == 0)
        break;

    // В противном случае, добавляем число к общей сумме
    sum += val;
}

std::cout << "The sum of all the numbers you entered is " << sum << "\n";

return 0;
}
```

Я не понял,как for считает,сколько раз я вводил числа, и если это число превышает 10,то программа завершается?Из-за чего так происходит

Comment: Попробуйте переформулировать вопрос. Что значит "почему"?

Comment: Я не понял,как for считает,сколько раз я вводил числа, и если это число превышает 10,то программа завершается?Из-за чего так происходит

Comment: Если вы `count<10`  поменяете на `count<100`, то вам придется вводить данные 100 раз :). `++count` в конце строчки с `for` как бы инкрементирует `count`, то есть добавляет к текущему значению единицу. Эта инструкция (`++count`) выполняется после выполнения тела цикла, а затем сравнивается с условием `count<10`. Если результат ложен цикл прекращается

Comment: Выходов из цикла два - либо при нарушении условия (`count < 10`), либо из тела по `break`, который срабатывает при `val==0`. А на каждой итерации `count` увеличивается на 1.

Comment: Я все понял,спасибо!!

Comment: А может кто-то дать свои социальные сети,просто у меня бывают маленькие вопросы,которые настолько маленькие,что на стак оверфлоу стыдно задавать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оператор `for` состоит из четырех операторов

```cpp
for (op1; op2; op3)
  op4
```

которые выполняются в таком порядке

```cpp
op1;
while (op2) {
  op4;
  op3;
}
```

соответственно ваш цикл

```cpp
for (int count=0; count < 10; ++count) {
  ......
}
```

может быть переписан в такой вид

```cpp
int count=0;
while (count < 10) {
  ......
  ++count;
}
```